# Changing the svg circle path color in mateiral icons

Tags: css, svg

I have the material svg added with fill and stroke properties

```css
.sample {
  background-color: black;
}

svg >path:last-child {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #14B005;
}
```

```html
<div class='sample'>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zM9.29 16.29L5.7 12.7c-.39-.39-.39-1.02 0-1.41.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0L10 14.17l6.88-6.88c.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0 .39.39.39 1.02 0 1.41l-7.59 7.59c-.38.39-1.02.39-1.41 0z"/></svg>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is, I don't want to have the circle with green, it should be white and if you zoom little the tick has a black checked line I think its the background color black, I need to remove both of these

how can I achieve this or should i use two tone from material icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The styling problem is that the circle and check mark are drawn with the same patch
I split one patch into separate patches. One patch for the circle, the second patch for the tick.

Splitting patches by second M command

It was:

```
path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zM9.29 16.29L5.7 12.7c-.39-.39-.39-1.02 0-1.41.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0L10 14.17l6.88-6.88c.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0 .39.39.39 1.02 0 1.41l-7.59 7.59c-.38.39-1.02.39-1.41 0z"/>
```

became

```
<path class="circle" d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2z"/>
   <path class="check"  d="M9.29 16.29L5.7 12.7c-.39-.39-.39-1.02 0-1.41.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0L10 14.17l6.88-6.88c.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0 .39.39.39 1.02 0 1.41l-7.59 7.59c-.38.39-1.02.39-1.41 0z"/>
```

With this type of recording, it becomes possible to change the colors of the circle and the checkmark independently.

```css
.sample {
  background-color: black;
}

.rect {
  fill: black;
  stroke: #14B005;
}  
.circle {
  fill: white;
  }
.check {
  fill: #14B005;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width:1;
}
```

```html
<div class='sample'>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
  <path class="rect" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" />
  
  <path class="circle" d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2z"/>
   <path class="check"  d="M9.29 16.29L5.7 12.7c-.39-.39-.39-1.02 0-1.41.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0L10 14.17l6.88-6.88c.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0 .39.39.39 1.02 0 1.41l-7.59 7.59c-.38.39-1.02.39-1.41 0z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Whatever the solution i posted is that correct, don't have much idea on the svg thats why

Comment: One more doubt, how did you split this path, https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=error_outline&style=baseline, i need this one also in the same way, instead of green i need to have red.

Comment: @ alexandr any help on this ?

Comment: i have used the same approach by splitting starting with "M' into two path tags

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS I don’t understand yet what the problem is to replace the color with red in styles. Maybe you’d better ask a new question where describe the problem in detail

Comment: @ alexandr, https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=error_outline&style=baseline the same way i need to do for this icon, but with approach that i have added was able to solve this

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS  for icon error_outline need red color?

Comment: yes because on the question you have split based on the "M" two paths but when i tried i understood it won't work so i used the https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=priority_high&style=baseline, this one and used the approach what i have answered

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS I tried this icon.(error_outline)  We need a new approach. Therefore, it's better to ask a new question. I will try to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution

1. Used another svg without any circle, just a tick
2. made the svg to `border-radius:50%` to look round
3. give the color for th svg and the path

```css
.sample {
  background-color: black;
}

svg {
  border-radius: 50%
}

svg>path:first-child {
 fill: white;
}

svg>path:last-child {
 fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='sample'>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
    <path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z" />
  </svg>

</div>
```